# GitLab CICD deployment with GitLab Environment branches flow

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm trying to setup a gitlab cicd pipeline flow for my **docker-based web app projects**. The idea is to use the **gitlab environment branches flow** to make developed code bubble towards the prod environment, which is publicly exposed on the internet.

From the **master** branch, I develop a **feature** on a dedicated branch, then I open a **merge request** into **master**. If tests pass and the merge request is accepted, a particular job creates a build **tagged** docker image for my app, which is stored on the project container registry. This is done through a job which uses **kaniko** to create an image tagged both with **latest** and the **CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA**, to ensure image reproducibility.

Then, a **merge request** is opened into **staging** to **deploy** the **latest** tagged image into staging. If everything goes fine and I subsequently want to deploy into prod, I **git tag** the current **commit** with semantic versioning (i.e. vX.Y.Z). The tagging procedure triggers a **tag pipeline** with which I create a new **semantic versioned image tag** out of the staging image version thanks to **crane** (which avoids me to rebuild a new image).

Now I open a **merge request** into **prod**, which is supposed to do the deployment in production. Here I have a problem. Ideally, imho, it would be better to deploy the image with the semantic versioning tag. This is the best way to ensure reproducibility over time, and helps understanding exactly which image version is run in prod. The problem is that gitlab CICD pipeline alternatively provides the tag name or the branch name. Meaning: there is no way to access both the git tag name and the branch within a pipeline, independently of its type (branch/ tag). To me, both of them should be on the contrary available in both types of pipelines.

If I have the tag, I lose the possibility to know in which branch I am. This can cause to redeploy to prod from wherever I am tagging, which could lead to undesired deployments.
Conversely, if I have the branch name, I'm sure I'm deploying when I'm merging into production, but I cannot deploy the image version I want through the git tag. Yes, I could use the COMMIT_SHORT_SHA, but this makes it useless to produce a semantic versioned tagged image in the registry, which would be the best option to know exactly what is deployed into prod.

Any idea on how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, you want to be able to get both commit tag and branch name in the pipeline. You can use `CI_COMMIT_TAG` for the tag and execute the following command to get the branch name in the variable TAG_BRANCH `TAG_BRANCH=$(git branch --contains tags/CI_COMMIT_TAG)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This solves the problem of getting the branch but I fear it is not feasible in my case. What I want is to trigger the deployment on a branch pipeline, resulting of the merge request being merged into prod. Here I don't have access to CI_COMMIT_TAG. Nevertheless you put me on the right path, since now it is about solving the opposite problem, meaning finding the tag out of the current commit. This can be done with a proper git command. Sad to see this info doesn't come out of GitLab variables, but this is still a good workaround. Thank you!